# Merge the "volume" and "volume-control" – or eliminate the ambiguity?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just discovered we've got another pair of obviously very similar or even duplicate tags:

- [volume](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) (×30): "For questions related to volume control (audio). Do not confuse it with disk volumes."
- [volume-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume-control) (×100): "Questions that deal with the volume control of Android devices; either using the hardware controls (Volume Keys) or software controls (Apps and widgets)."

On a first glance, and arguing by their tag excerpt, they serve the very same purpose – so I was about to suggest a merge.

A second look however reveals a tiny difference: `volume` seems to focus more on "hardware" (in the sense of "breaking limits": getting the max out of it by overcoming "safety locks"), while `volume-control` is rather mixed (normalisation, auto-adjusts, how to adjust several channels separately, etc.). Which brings up a second option: let us have both, but clearly pointing out in the tag excerpts/wikis which is which (including a "cleanup/re-tag" on existing questions).

Which way to go? Voters for the second option: How to best describe the tags in this case, to make the difference clear (guess only `volume` would need its excerpt updated then)?